# How to plot FFTs of pressure values from .svc files of 129 users

Tags: python

I have 129 users with each of their task file stored in '.svc'. The 6th column in the .svc file contains pressure values. I want to plot the pressure FFT for each user (i.e. to get 129 FFT plots) and save those FFT results in separate folders of class A,B or C. The classes A,B,C are present in the form of a data frame in my code which shows each user in their respective class via one hot encoding. This is what I have done so far:

```
N = 129
T = 1
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N//2)   #create new x-axis: frequency from signal

users_files = glob.glob(r"/content/drive/MyDrive/DataEmothaw/Collection*/user000**/")
for user_file in users_files:
 file_path=glob.glob(user_file+'/session00001/u000**s00001_hw00001.svc',recursive = True)
  for file in file_path:
    with open(file) as f:
      pressure_values = 0
      next(f)
      for i, line in enumerate(f):
          row = [col for col in line.rstrip().split(delimiter)] 
          try:                            
            pressure_values = int(row[pCOL])    #all pressure values of each user
            #print(pressure_values)
            
          except:
            pass
  y = pressure_values  
  yf = fft(y)        
  plt.plot(xf, abs(yf[0:N//2]), label = 'Pressure FFT of user __')
  plt.xticks([]) 
  plt.yticks([]) 
  #plt.savefig(r"/content/drive/MyDrive/MS thesis/Pressure FFT of user__.png") #add user number
  plt.show()
```